# How to generate junit.xml using minil test?

Tags: perl, junit, perl-module, tap

I am using [`minilla`](https://metacpan.org/release/Minilla) for generating my module scaffold. While it works very well for me, I'd like to get generated `junit.xml` file with test results when running `minil test`.

I found that it is possible to specify `tap_harness_args` in `minil.toml` configuration file. I tried

```
[tap_harness_args]
formatter_class = "TAP::Formatter::JUnit"
```

which ensures that the tests output is formatted in JUnit format. That works well but the output is mixed up with minilla's other output so I can't easily redirect it to a file. Is there a way how to get only the test results to a file? Optimally, I'd still like to see the test results in TAP format in my terminal output at the same time (but I can live without it).

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: can't you use the `a<file.tgz>` option in HARNESS_OPTIONS in [TAP::Harness::Env](http://p3rl.org/TAP::Harness::Env)?

Comment: I tried, unfortunately without any success. The file just didn't appear.